# If checkbox is checked then insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, checked

I want to insert into my mysql database only those rows that have a checked checkbox at the end.

Since i have several tables and table data cells that have the same name, then my data is stored in arrays (product_name[] etc.):

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                            <?php    
                                while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

                                    echo "<table id='tbl'>
                                    <thead><th name='category[]'>".$res['category_name']."</th></thead>                                   
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name='product_name[]' id='name' type='text'></td>
                                        <td><input name='quantity[]' type='text' value='1'></td>
                                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>";
                            
                                }
                            ?>
                            </table>
                        <div class="bottom-btn">
                            <button id="submit" type="submit">Lisa märgitud külmkappi</button>
                        </div>
</form>
```

Do i have to store the checkboxes in array as well (check[])?

My php code for the insert:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        // $check = $_POST['check'];
            
foreach($product_name as $i=>$product_name)
            {if(!empty($product_name)){

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (id, product_name, category, quantity, expiration_date, barcode) VALUES ('','$product_name', '', '$quantity[$i]', '', '')";
                        
                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss",$param_product_name, $param_quantity);
                        
                        $param_product_name = $product_name;
                        $param_quantity=$quantity;

                        
                        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                            header("location: myFridge.php");
                        } else{
                            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                        }
                        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    }
            }
        }
   
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
```

So far i have tried this: `if(!empty($_POST['check']))` and this `if(isset($_POST['check'])` , but those did not work.

How to check if checkbox is checked before inserting data to database?

EDIT. WORKING.

I added this code to my page to make an array of checkbox on and off values:

```
function getAllCheckboxValues($check){
        $found = array();
        foreach ($check as $key => $val){
            if($val == 'on'){
                $found[] = $key;
            }
        }
        foreach($found as $kev_f => $val_f){
            unset($check[$val_f-1]);
        }
        $final_arr = array();

        return $final_arr = array_values($check);

    }

    $checkbox_arr = getAllCheckboxValues($_POST['check']);
```

And also added a hidden input before every checkbox:

```
<input type='hidden' name='check[]' value='off'>
```

Then matched the checbox array with my products array and voila!

Comment: Checkboxes behave differently from other form elements, in that they only cause an entry in the form submission data set, when they are checked. A different way to solve this, would be that you _specify_ the array index in your form field names upfront, `name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"`, etc. Then you can loop over `$_POST['product_name']`, and via the array index `$i`, you can check if a corresponding entry `$_POST['check'][$i]` exists, or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `var_dump($_POST)` to see whats in your post request. That always helps when facing issues like that.

Checkboxes come with the value `on` if they are checked and `off` if they are not, so it will never be empty and always be set, which is why your checks did not work. You should check `if($_POST['check'] === 'on')` instead.

Comment: I tried to make an array from checkbox 'on' and 'off' values so that i can connect the right checkbox with my table row. But it only shows me 'on' values, so that my array is not correct. It skips the 'off' checkboxes and so the indexes in my array are wrong and it inserts wrong rows to my database. Like if my array item with index 1 should be 'off' then it skips that and finds the next 'on' and puts that value in index 1 in that array, so later it connects wrong checkbox with wrong table row. If that makes any sense.